# Android Loading listview items from service results in hang

Tags: android, listview, service, message-queue, serviceconnection

In my Android application, I have a ListActivity. This ListActivity uses a SimpleAdapter that I fill with items from my service. So, in my code, I do:

```
MySuperCoolService.Binder serviceBinder = null;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service connection: connected!");
            serviceBinder = (MySuperCoolService.Binder)service;
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service connection: disconnected");
            serviceBinder = null;
        }
    };
bindService(new Intent(this, MySuperCoolService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
while(serviceBinder==null) {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
// now retrieve from service using binder and set list adapter
```

This whole operation takes hardly any time (less than a second), so I want it to run in the UI thread. See my onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fillDataUsingCodeAbove();
}
```

The reason I want this to run in the UI thread is that if you have a list item selected, or you have scrolled to a certain position in the ListView, and you rotate the device or take out the keyboard or something (to trigger a configuration change) when my activity is restarted, Android will try to restore the state right after onCreate. But, if I run it in a separate thread, it will not. Also there is a cool fadein animation too :)
The problem I am having with running it in the UI thread is that when I try to bind to the service, that service bind request gets put onto the message queue. But then when I go into my loop, I stop the message queue from looping. So my program hangs, because it's waiting for the service to get bound, and the service won't get bound until the loop ends. I have thought of putting `Looper.loop()` inside my loop, but that just hangs it at `Looper.loop()` (I don't know why.)
Sorry for such a long question,
Isaac Waller

Comment: You can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) or it is good way to use [Retrofit for android.](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), it won't loca UI thread and wouldn't be much more complicated than what you already have.